# Could not commit JPA transaction / error while committing the transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My code : 
I got Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transactio.

```
 <spring-boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

The error occured when classeB has a collection of classeC

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

    private Repository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceImpl(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public CLASSEA add(Long id, CLASSEB classeB) {
        Optional<CLASSEA > optionalClasseA = repository.findById(id);

        if (optionalClasseA.isPresent()) {
            CLASSEA classA= optionalClasseA .get();
            classA.addClasseB(classeB);
            return repository.save(classA);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
public class CLASSEA implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classeA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<CLASSEB> classB= new HashSet<>();
}

public class CLASSEB implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classeB", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<CLASSEC> classeC= new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("paymentItems")
    private ClasseA classeA;

}

@Entity
public class CLASSEC implements Serializable {
   @ManyToOne
   private CLASSEB classeB;
}
```

POST REQUEST :

```
classe B : {
    "amount": 7845,
    "classeC": [ {  ..
    }],
    "classeA": null,

    "day": "2018-07-19T10:46:04.245+02:00",
    "id": null
}
```

Comment: There is no field `classeB ` in the `CLASSEC` entity. Hence your mapping information is wrong. The same applies to `CLASSEB` which should have a `classeA` field. At least that is what you told JPA how it should be.

Comment: I just forgot to copy all the mapping